# Which approximation functions does NDSolve take when solving second order ODE with the finite element method? Are they linear in parts or some other?

Tags: finite-element-method

This is the code that I have

```
ode =y''[t] +0y'[t]+25y[t]-1;
sol = NDSolve[{ode == NeumannValue[0, t==5], DirichletCondition[y[t]==0, t==0]},y,{t,0,5}, Method -> {"FiniteElement", "MeshOptions" -> "MaxCellMeasure" ->0.5}];
```

Comment: FEM by default uses 2nd order Serendipity shape functions

Answer (score 1):

I guess that by "linear in parts" you mean that approximation functions are triangular tents.

These triangular tents are *not* the approximations functions that NDSolve uses in your example.

If you want NDSolve to use these tent functions, add the option "MeshOrder"->1, like in this example:

```
ode = y''[t] + 0 y'[t] + 25 y[t] - 1;
solMeshOrder1 = 
  NDSolve[{ode == NeumannValue[0, t == 5], 
    DirichletCondition[y[t] == 0, t == 0]}, y, {t, 0, 5}, 
   Method -> {"FiniteElement", 
     "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.5, "MeshOrder" -> 1}}];

solElementMesh = (solMeshOrder1[[1, 1, 2]])["ElementMesh"];
solElementMesh["MeshOrder"]
solElementMesh["Coordinates"]
```

> 1
>
> {{0.}, {0.5}, {1.}, {1.5}, {2.}, {2.5}, {3.}, {3.5}, {4.}, {4.5}, {5.}}

`solElementMesh["Coordinates"]` returns the 11 coordinates of the top of the 11 tents functions.

The default values for "MeshFunction" is 2. In that case there are 10 more functions, giving a total of 21 functions. These 10 functions are additional non-linear function (The 11 initial functions stay unchanged).

Comment: Note that your approach to use the finite element method on a temporal problem is rare. Most temporal problems are evolution problems : One gives initial conditions and let the system lives is life (no boundary conditions at the end of the domain).